# Rendering html code using TagBuilder and ASP.NET MVC 4 (with Razor engine)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to render `li` items using TagBuilder.

My function

```
public static string RenderListTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string labelText, string action, string controller, bool isAdmin, string listCssClass = "")
        {
            string value = string.Empty;

            TagBuilder li = new TagBuilder("li");
            TagBuilder anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
            UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(action) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller))
            {
                anchor.MergeAttribute("href", "#");
            }
            else
            {
                anchor.MergeAttribute("href", urlHelper.Action(action, controller, new
                {
                    area = isAdmin ? "Admin" : ""
                }));
            }

            anchor.SetInnerText(labelText);

            if (action.IsEqualWith(helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
            {
                li.MergeAttribute("class", "active");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listCssClass))
            {
                li.MergeAttribute("class", listCssClass);
            }

            li.SetInnerText(anchor.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

            return li.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }
```

When I call using the following code:

```
@Html.RenderListTag("Home", "Index", "Contents", false)
@Html.RenderListTag("About", "About", "Home", false)
@Html.RenderListTag("Contact", "Contact", "Home", false)
@Html.RenderListTag("Show toolbar", "", "", false, "options no-display")
@Html.RenderListTag("CMS", "Index", "Home", true)
```

The results is printed as text NOT html tag.

```
<li class="active">&lt;a href=&quot;/Contents&quot;&gt;Home&lt;/a&gt;</li> <li>&lt;a href=&quot;/Home/About&quot;&gt;About&lt;/a&gt;</li> <li>&lt;a href=&quot;/Home/Contact&quot;&gt;Contact&lt;/a&gt;</li> <li class="options no-display">&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;Show toolbar&lt;/a&gt;</li> <li class="active">&lt;a href=&quot;/Admin/Home&quot;&gt;CMS&lt;/a&gt;</li>
```

I want to print the HTML tag not text.

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw(Html.RenderListTag("CMS", "Index", "Home", true))`

Comment: All strinsg in MVC are automatically HTML encoded so we use Raw()

Comment: Your code works and I voted up. But I will follow my method described above.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer, extensions do not need to be wrapped with Raw to work. Extensions outputting the tag as text havn't been written correctly (In this case) . See op's "I found my Mistake"

Comment: Using return type MvcHtmlString instead of string should also fix the problem no ?

Answer (score 29):

I found my mistake :)

I used

```
li.SetInnerText(anchor.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
```

The correct way is

```
li.InnerHtml = anchor.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
```

I changed type of my function from `string` to `MvcHtmlString` like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderListTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string labelText, string action, string controller, bool isAdmin, string listCssClass = "")
```

And the return of function is:

```
return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
```

Now, works.

Comment: This is the most correct answer.  Why go to all the trouble to build an HTML helper only to have to use Html.Raw to render it?...that is the whole point of MvcHtmlString.

Comment: I'd always used: `return new HtmlString(li.ToString());` (`HtmlString` is in `System.Web`) in NET 4.0

Answer (score 5):

You must return a **MvcHtmlString** from method

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderListTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string labelText, string action, string controller, bool isAdmin, string listCssClass = "")
{
    string value = string.Empty;

    TagBuilder li = new TagBuilder("li");
    TagBuilder anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(action) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller))
    {
        anchor.MergeAttribute("href", "#");
    }
    else
    {
        anchor.MergeAttribute("href", urlHelper.Action(action, controller, new
        {
            area = isAdmin ? "Admin" : ""
        }));
    }

    anchor.SetInnerText(labelText);

    if (action.IsEqualWith(helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
    {
        li.MergeAttribute("class", "active");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listCssClass))
    {
        li.MergeAttribute("class", listCssClass);
    }

    li.SetInnerText(anchor.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

    return new MvcHtmlString(li.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last line to:

`return helper.Raw(li.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)).ToHtmlString();`

Comment: Well, it seems like the `SetInnerText` was the real problem!

Comment: Yes, true. That was my pain :))

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, I have a good friend in the static method HtmlDecode of the HttpUtility class. Try: return MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(li.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)));

HTH